# How to display first time zero value if there is no value in database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table name called as request and column name is points. I have to display zero if there is no value in that column. Would you help me in this?

```
$admin_total="SELECT register_points FROM request where Id=2";
$total_result = $conn->query($admin_total);
if (isset($total_result->num_rows) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $total_result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $total_records=$row['register_points'];
  }
 }
echo $total_records;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can try this:-empty($row['register_points'])?0:$row['register_points']; OR can you not set column register_points default value to null in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to handle this on the MySQL side using `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(register_points, 0) AS register_points
FROM request
WHERE Id = 2
```

This assumes that the `register_points` column is a nullable numeric type.  If it be text, then the above would also work though we might want to use a cast of some sort.

Comment: you can also use `IFNULL`

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Tim, I have one doubt. In case. I am using a query like select * from request where id=2 than how can  i add the zero for multiple coulmn

Comment: You would have to list out the columns individually.  You _might_ be able to do `SELECT *, COALESCE(register_points, 0) AS effective_points` and then fish out the columns you want on the PHP side.  But this would mean sort of selecting the points column twice.

Comment: Can you help me in this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908975/update-query-is-not-working-using-php?noredirect=1#comment70999857_41908975